# Problems using SerialPort to communicate between Node.js and Arduino

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to build a Node.js server that sends Data to an Arduino and the Arduino send this same Data back, I'm able to access any data from the Arduino to my computer, but not send data to the Arduino, I'm using SerialPort

This is my code in the Arduino IDE. My Arduino should be receiving '1', which is 49 in ASCII. Then, if it actually receives 49, it will send the data back.

```
char incomingByte;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  incomingByte = Serial.read();
  if (incomingByte == 49) {
    Serial.write(incomingByte);
  }
}
```

In my Node.js file, I'm trying to send "1" and I'm logging anything that I receive.

```
const { SerialPort } = require('serialport');

const port = new SerialPort('/dev/cu.usbmodem14201', {
  baudRate: 9600,
  dataBits: 8,
  stopBits: 1,
  parity: 'none'
});

port.on('open', () => {
  port.write('1');
});

port.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data.toString());
});

port.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Error:', err);
});
```

Comment: Your code work as expected *provided* that you don't open the Serial Monitor on your Arduino.

Comment: some Arduinos reset on new USB connection and stay in the bootloader for a few seconds

Comment: @Colby You have been suggesting edits that duplicate the title instead of just fixing the capitalization as you seem to think. For example, [your suggested edit to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34067023) changed the title to "*Problems using SerialPort to communicate between Node.js and Arduinoproblems using SerialPort to communicate between Node.js and Arduino*" (note that it's duplicated). While fixing the capitalization is OK, when you do so, please make sure that the new title makes sense.

Comment: @Colby Also, when you edit, please try to fix other issues as well. For example in [this other edit you suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/34060004) there were a lot of spelling mistakes in the body that you didn't fix.